# Perl nested parentheses expression

Tags: regex, perl, nested, expression, parentheses

How do I use perl regex to extract the contents within the outermost parentheses?

text   = (-(A + (B - C)))

output = -(A + (B - C))

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with this `(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))` and there are several
ways to do it.

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (                       # (1 start), Recursion code group
      \(                      # Opening (
      (                       # (2 start), Capture, inner core
           (?:                     # Cluster group
                [^()]++                 # Possesive, not parenth's
             |                        # or,
                (?1)                    # Recurse to group 1
           )*                      # End cluster, do 0 to many times
      )                       # (2 end)
      \)                      # Closing )
 )                       # (1 end)
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 4 , len 16 ) 
(-(A + (B - C)))  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 4 , len 16 ) 
(-(A + (B - C)))  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 5 , len 14 ) 
-(A + (B - C))
```

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I expect the following to be faster because it only tries to recurse when it must: `\( ( [^()]* (?: \( (?1) \) [^()]* )* ) \)`

Comment: @ikegami I'd think the `++` should make them pretty much the same

Comment: @ikegami  - Yes, it appears %30 faster than the alternation. Sort of unrolled loop meets recursion.

Comment: This is unnecessarily elaborate. The OP doesn't ask that the string should be tested to ensure the parentheses are balanced, just that the string within the outermost pair is extracted

Comment: @ikegami - Your unrolled recursive loop is _Brilliant!_ Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that anything more than this is required

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $text = "(-(A + (B - C)))";

my ($result) = $text =~ / \( (.*) \) /x;

print $result, "\n";
```

#### output

```
-(A + (B - C))
```

The pattern captures everything from after the first opening parenthesis to before the last closing parenthesis. From your question, I don't think there's a need to check that the string is balanced